# CodeIgniter Restful API error status: false Method: Unknown

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am having a problem regarding getting response from the Restful API in CodeIgniter. Here is my controller

```
public function user_post() {
  if(!empty($userData['name']) && !empty($userData['email']) && 
  !empty($userData['gender']) && !empty($userData['age']) && 
  !empty($userData['phone']) && !empty($userData['password'])){
    //insert user data
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $enc_password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
    $insert = $this->auth_model->insert( $uuid, $enc_password,$now); 
    //check if the user data inserted
    if(!$insert){
      //set the response and exit
      $this->response([
      "status" => TRUE,
      "message" => "User has been added successfully."
      ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }else{
      //set the response and exit
      $this->response("Some problems occurred, please try again.", 
      REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }else{
    //set the response and exit
    $this->response("Provide complete user information to create.", 
    REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

Please Help If U have any Solutions..

Answer (score 0):

**Your request should be**

```
url: 'https://yoursite.com/api/v1/user'
method: 'post'
```

Since your using `REST_Controller` rather than `CI_Controller`

**Change**

```
$this->input->post('password')
```

**Into this**

```
$this->post('password')
```

this is same with the other HTTP Requests

```
$this->post();
$this->get();
$this->put();
$this->delete();
```

Comment: Hi there .. I tried that still same error . I made othe post request in model. Do I need to do more changes ?

Comment: Can you also post your Ajax?